# hi im trying to run a bash script using python but i am geting a permission error when i try to run it with python

Tags: python, bash

So long story short i am making an auto mater using python and bash so i can just run one python file and all my docker containers and self made scripts can run but every time i try to run a bash script i get permission 13 (bare in mind I did use the chmod u+x command)

here is the code:

```
import os

from colorama import Fore

import time

import subprocess

while True:

    print(Fore.GREEN + "Welcome\n")
    print("To Automater")

    options = print(Fore.WHITE + """what would you like to do?\n1.Start Containers\n2.Stop Containers\n3.Run A script\n4.Add containers\n5.Exit\n""")

    started = input("1-4:\n")

    if started == "1":
        print(Fore.RED + "Starting containers")
        #os.startfile(Start_Containers.sh)
        subprocess.call(["./Start_Containers.sh"])
```

and here is the error i get:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: './Start_Containers.sh'
Process finished with exit code 1
```

here is all the code:

```
import os
from colorama import Fore
import time
import subprocess

while True:

    print(Fore.GREEN + "Welcome\n")
    print("To Automater")

    options = print(Fore.WHITE + """what would you like to do?\n1.Start Containers\n2.Stop Containers\n3.Run A script\n4.Add containers\n5.Exit\n""")

    started = input("1-4:\n")

    if started == "1":
        print(Fore.RED + "Starting containers")
        #os.startfile(Start_Containers.sh)
        subprocess.call(["./Start_Containers.sh"])

    if started == "2":
        print(Fore.RED + "Stoping containers")
        os.startfile("./Stop_Containers.sh")

    elif started == "3":
        Scripts = []

        for files in os.listdir():
            Scripts.append(files)
            print(Scripts)

    elif started =="4":
        while True:
            add_container = input("Would you like to add a container [y/N]")
            if add_container.upper() == "Y":
                print("Ok Lets add some")
                added_containers = input("ok lets add a container")

            elif add_container.upper() == "N":
                break
                exit()

    elif started == "5":
        print(Fore.GREEN + "Thank you for using Automater")
        time.sleep(1)
        break
        exit()
```

Comment: What are the permissions on `Start_Containers.sh`? The user who runs the Python script needs to have read and execute permission to it.

Comment: Try `chmod a+rx Start_Containers.sh`

Comment: hi i tried using the chmod a+rx command but now i am not getting permission error 13 but i am getting this error: OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error: './Start_Containers.sh'

Comment: Do the `.sh` scripts have [shebangs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_\(Unix\))?

Comment: no they do not only the python code Edit:Adding a shebang fixed the problem, Thank You

Answer (score -2):

To run bash script, looks like you need admin access. Instead of running the script with `python <script_name>.py`, run it with `sudo python <script_name>.py` on linux.

Strictly speaking, this is very, very bad practice. But if you are doing this just for fun(which it looks like you are), it's ok. But never, EVER do this on anything even remotely important.

Comment: Since when do you need admin access to run shell script?

Comment: "*These are the forbidden techniques*" Says *who*?

Comment: i know im just trying to build up my skill as i want to be a software engineer when i grow up

Comment: i just added all the code into the post if you want to reveiw all the code

Comment: Running with `sudo` is a terrible idea. Whatever the script does runs as root, including maybe a `rm -rf $VAR/` and if `VAR` is not defined you wipe your installation. It also means that any files and directories created will be owned by root, and you'll have to `chown` them to work with them normally, or get into more bad unnecessary `sudo` habits. Only run with `sudo` if you need to run commands that only root can run.

Comment: hi do i run rm -rf $VAR in the terminal or do i integrate it into my python code

Comment: @pugnaciousunrest You don't. He was illustrating a dangerous command that might be in the script and shouldn't be executed as root.

Comment: i ran it but not as root so im good

Comment: @Robert i know, that is why i added the second paragraph. It is a bad practice. I don't understand what you are adding to this discussion.

Comment: Since it's bad practice, maybe don't suggest it at all? Instead of first suggesting it and then saying "it's bad practice". There may always be people that don't read the full answer and just copy & paste whatever looks like it could solve the problem. And you could of course say that's their problem, and you would be right, but still... Anyway, `sudo` won't help if the problem was the missing shebang line or if it was a script file permissions issue anyway. IMHO you should delete this answer.